# UML diagram for smart home system

Tags: architecture, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm doing a use case diagram for a smart home system, which is centralized by a server.

Should I include the devices as an actor in the system, because the devices use services, and create triggers and actions? Or can an actor only be a person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the relevant definition reminded by qwerty_so, I'd like to add some more hints:

- If the devices are autonomous systems that interact with the system under consideration for your use-cases, they can be actors.
- If the devices are not autonomous and are controlled by your central server and are in reality a part of this system, they should not be actors, because actors are necessarily external to the system.

Comment: Thanks both of you, then I dont use them as an actor. I think it is unclear for many people, and I saw too many bad examples.

Comment: It depends on your viewpoint. You can well see them as external/individual actors if you design a system independent of any attached sensor.

Answer (score 2):

An actor is anything that acts (with the system under consideration), no matter being human or not. UML 2.5 p. 645:

> An Actor specifies a role played by a user or any other system that interacts with the subject.